# Printing Report in CiviCase

Tags: civicase, reports, windows

Editing original post: When I click "Print Report" from a case, the page is not pulling the CSS and activities are not showing. After the page reloads, I receive an error:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Empty string supplied as input in    CRM_Case_Audit_Audit->getActivities() (line 33 of
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Case\Audit\Audit.php).

Originally, the conversation on Mattermost lead to a suspicion that this might be a Windows server issue. It's unclear now, but I do see this issue occur in both of my CiviCRM on Xampp windows. In Linux, I don't have this problem.

Has anyone received this error before?

Comment: Can you be more specific or share part of the conversation? Do you mean the server is windows? On windows browsers I've never seen a problem. Also the version #'s of all the various components would be helpful.

Comment: Oh I see in the title you said server. I run a dev copy on my laptop all the time. It's WAMP so it's apache not IIS, but I don't see any issues.

Comment: Ugh, that's so strange. What CiviCRM version are you on?

Comment: Doubt this is Windows specific at this point

Comment: Based on the error my first guess might be related to case type. Are they stock case types in the sites where you're seeing the error?